# Is it okay to have the same key for these three files, "pkgs-osrf-archive-keyring.gpg", "gazebo-archive-keyring.gpg"?

Tags: apt, updates, repository, gnupg

I have the same PGP key values for both the above mentioned .gpg files,
this is how it looks

-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=YM5F
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----

I am getting an error when I use sudo apt update,
how to proceed on this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the actual "error when [you] use sudo apt update"